# How do I deal with the message saying "unknown option : wall" in code blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I work on code blocks 13.12, I am a beginner. Whenever I click the build button a message box pops up saying " UNKNOWN OPTION : Wall"

Please help me with this problem.

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot it appears that you have inadvertently configured CodeBlocks to use `codeblocks.exe` as your compiler. Instead use e.g. `g++`.